# Get rid of infinity in matrix elements (by separate definition of diagonal and off-diagonal elements)

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I want to generate a matrix in which the elements have the below rule to be generated:

```
Table[KroneckerDelta[n, m] (m + n (1 - 1/(\[Pi] n^2))) +
(1 - KroneckerDelta[n, m]) (1/( n - m)),
{n, 1, 10}, {m, 1, 10}];
```

As we know the matrix has some diagonal elements which are determined by `KroneckerDelta[n, m](m + n (1 - 1/(\[Pi] n^2)))` and off-diagonal elements which are defined by `(1 - KroneckerDelta[n, m]) (1/( n - m))`

**Problem**

When `m=n`, `(1/( n - m))` gets infinity for diagonal elements. But we know that the duty of `(1 - KroneckerDelta[n, m])` is preventing generation diagonal elements with `1/(n-m)`! how can I solve this problem?!

Comment: `SparseArray[{{n_, n_} :> 
    n + n (1 - 1/(\[Pi] n^2)), {m_, n_} /; m != n :> 1/(n - m)}, {10, 
   10}] // Normal`

Comment: @march you always surprise me with your answers. Please let me understand step by step your solution

Comment: `SparseArray` is nice because it allows you to define the matrix elements using `Pattern`s. So `{n_, n_} :> n + n (1 - 1/(\[Pi] n^2))` means replace all entries indexed as `(n,n)` (i.e. diagonal entries) with `n + n (1 - 1/(\[Pi] n^2))`, and `{m_, n_} /; m != n :> 1/(n - m)}` uses `Condition` to replace entry `(m,n)` with `1/(n - m)` *only if* `m` and `n` are unequal, and so it never evaluates `1/(n - m)` with `n==m`. Otherwise, look up the documentation for `SparseArray`.

Comment: Why insist on using `KroneckerDelta[]`? Either of `Table[If[n == m, m + n (1 - 1/(π n^2)), 1/(n - m)], {n, 10}, {m, 10}]` or `ToeplitzMatrix[Prepend[1/Range[9], 0], Prepend[-1/Range[9], 0]] + DiagonalMatrix[Table[2 n - 1/(π n), {n, 10}]]` works.

Comment: @ march, I have seen SparseArray but I did not know its duty! with your solution I have been familiar to that with its detail. It is so flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) is nice because it allows you to define the matrix elements using Patterns. So

```
{n_, n_} :> n + n (1 - 1/(π n^2))
```

means replace all entries indexed as $(n,n)$ (i.e. diagonal entries) with `n + n (1 - 1/(π n^2))`, and

```
{m_, n_} /; m != n :> 1/(n - m)}
```

uses `Condition` to replace entry $(m,n)$ with `1/(n - m)` only if `m` and `n` are unequal, and so it never evaluates `1/(n - m)` with `n == m`.

Therefore,

```
mat = SparseArray[{{n_, n_} :> n + n (1 - 1/(π n^2)), {m_, n_} /; m != n :> 1/(n - m)}, {10, 10}] // Normal;
```

---

Alternatively, use [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m)'s solution that he posted in the comments:

```
mat = Table[If[n == m, m + n (1 - 1/(π n^2)), 1/(n - m)], {n, 10}, {m, 10}];
```

or

```
mat = ToeplitzMatrix[Prepend[1/Range[9], 0], Prepend[-1/Range[9], 0]]
        + DiagonalMatrix[Table[2 n - 1/(π n), {n, 10}]];
```

Then:

```
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: @J.M. I never assume! And as much as people find it annoying, I'm a fan of using "they" as a gender-less pronoun.

Comment: I'm glad that you did not, but that is tempered by my bias against "singular they". But we can agree to disagree. :)